# Turning an indexed array to json object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I use json_encode I get one large array filled with objects. How do I get the result to return many json objects.

e.g

**current result**

> [{data1}, {data2}, {data3}]

**the result i want**

> {{data1}, {data2}, {data3}}

**Snippet of my current code**

```
        $obj = json_decode($response);
        $list_of_obj = $obj->{'profiles'}->{'profile'}; // returns an array of json objects

        foreach($list_of_obj as $prov)
        {
            $list_of_prov[] = $prov;
        }

        file_put_contents('./results/profiles/' . time() . '-' . $count . '.json', json_encode($list_of_prov, true));
```

Comment: Confusing question.. "{data1}, {data2}, {data3}" is not valid JSON, for example. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Indeed, `{data1}, {data2}, {data3}` is NOT a valid JSON format, so you will not find JSON function returning such thing. What do you want to do ?

Comment: i updated the question to reflect correct json

Answer (score 0):

if you have a set of JSON objects this will generate an array of objects in PHP.

Here you are some documentation to help you:
http://json.org/